# display python script progress bar if running as systemd service

Tags: python, ubuntu

So I downloaded a python script to do some computation, I put it into the background via systemctl. It seems to work fine. But when I check the status I get stuff like at the end:

```
Dec 11 14:35:56 instance-1 bash[1635]: [2.0K blob data]
Dec 11 14:59:18 instance-1 bash[1635]: [2.0K blob data]
Dec 11 15:22:02 instance-1 bash[1635]: [2.0K blob data]
Dec 11 15:44:06 instance-1 bash[1635]: [2.0K blob data]
Dec 11 16:06:10 instance-1 bash[1635]: [2.0K blob data]
Dec 11 16:28:14 instance-1 bash[1635]: [2.0K blob data]
Dec 11 16:50:19 instance-1 bash[1635]: [1.9K blob data]
Dec 11 17:11:45 instance-1 bash[1635]: [2.0K blob data]
Dec 11 17:33:49 instance-1 bash[1635]: [2.0K blob data]
```

It's supposed to display a progress bar, from 0% to 100%. 
Is there a way to capture this progress bar? Just a snippet of it is fine, I just want to check the progress every hour or so.

This is running on a Google virtual machine, so that's one reason why I made it a daemon.

Comment: Can you provide the python script?

Comment: The script is on this repo: https://github.com/MortenHannemose/pytorch-vfi-cft   It's the slow_movie.py

Comment: first show in question (not in comment) code as text, not image or link

Comment: code may use progressbar which sends on screen, not to variable or file so you can't see it. Or it can send to `standard error` instead of `standard output` and it can't catch it to file. Some progressbar may also not work if they can't recognize terminal/console anc services works without access to terminal/console

Comment: Oh, so there's no way to fix this?